# Mac won't boot into OS X after update

Tags: 12.04, grub2, mac, refit, macbook-air

I run an update today on my Mac and it updated GRUB. I select it to leave it and not update it however when I reboot, rEFIt didn't appear and went straight to GRUB. I can boot into ubuntu but not into OS X.

When I shutdown and then turn the power back on while holding the OPTION key it does nothing and goes straight to the GRUB menu. I really need to get back to my OS X partition so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jorden

Comment: I was unaware that osx understood grub much less has updates for it. I would use a refit boot cd to fix the issue, it's likely you installed grub to the wrong location.

Comment: Can't boot a USB drive. Because I have no access to the menu that appears when holding option. 

I also have no DVD drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to my local Mac store and the technician had a look.

Turns out on newer versions of MacBooks you can `hold OPTION+R` 
This will bypass everything and take you straight into recovery.

- From there launch the disk utility manager
- Set Mac HD as your default drive.
- Reboot then login on OS X check in the preferences that Mac HD is the start up disk.
- Shutdown and you should hopefully see rEFIt and carry on as normal.

Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem I did.

As a note as well, if you're silly like me and didn't make a USB key (make one!) with your version of OS X! Lots of guides around on how to do it. 
[Guide: LifeHacker Burn OS X to DVD/USB](http://lifehacker.com/5928780/how-to-burn-os-x-mountain-lion-to-a-dvd-or-usb-flash-drive)